# what's the mean of just a typename in template parameter list?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming

```
template <typename Method, typename>
struct is_default : std::false_type { };
```

and what's the difference between the code above and this:

```
struct default_ { };
template <typename Method>
struct is_default<Method, decltype((void)
    static_cast<default_>(*(Method*)0)
)>
    : std::true_type
{ };
```

I can figure out that the last one is used to identify whether the `Method` is default. But I cannnot understand the use of  `decltype((void)static_cast<default_>((Method*)0))` , how does it work, and how it make the second code block different from the first code block? And what's the mean of just a `typename` in template parameter list like this `template <typename Method, typename>`?

Comment: Do you know what explicit and partial template specializations are?

Comment: @KerrekSB: I know the basic meaning of partia specialization, but i can ot figure out the difference of the two code blocks, I need some help.

Comment: Unnamed typename are like unnamed parameter. Here, `Enabler` or `AlwaysVoid` would be good names.

Comment: @Jarod42: Thanks. That's a good hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally understand it, forgive me, i'm a novice.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct default_ { };

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_default;

template <typename T>
struct i_am_default : default_ { };

template <>
struct i_am_default<float> { };

template <typename Method, typename>
struct is_default : std::false_type { };

template <typename Method>
struct is_default<Method, decltype((void)
    static_cast<default_>(*(Method*)0)
)>
    : std::true_type
{ };

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_default<i_am_default<int>>{} << '\n';
    std::cout << is_default<i_am_default<float>>{} << '\n';
    using type = i_am_default<int>;
    std::cout << typeid(decltype((void)static_cast<default_>(*(type*)0))).name() << '\n';
}
```

The code above is `c++ sfinae`.

The type that is not derived from default_ will be a compile time error, then the one derived from std::false_type will be chosen.

This is simple, but i am new to it, thanks all your comments.